# Django Cross Table Querysets

Tags: django, django-queryset

My model is defined as:

```
class Inventory(models.Model):
    items = models.ManyToManyField(Item, blank=True)
    scanned_items = models.ManyToManyField(Item, related_name='scanned_inventory_set', blank=True)
```

In a view, I am trying to get a list of all items that have not been scanned. Basically, it would have to be (items and not scanned_items). However, I do not know how to do the look up with the relationship between the two.

Comment: The `Inventory` model seems pointless in this situation. Why don't you have just an `Item` model that has a `scanned=BooleanField(default=False)` attribute?

Comment: I took out a lot of stuff from the inventory that was not relevance. For your interest, Inventory is a model so a report can be generated based on past inventories.

Answer (score 2):

You could do:

```
items_to_exclude = Inventory.objects.values_list('items', flat=True)
items = Items.objects.exclude(id__in=items_to_exclude)
```